# create sequence steps [animation] with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie at javascript.

I want to create some sequence actions, step by step.
And so, let's imagine i have 10s Timeline intro for this web site below:

**Steps**

1. Show Logo
2. Show Web site name
3. show My name
4. and many many other actions ....

---

Here is my attempt

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var bod = document.getElementById("_8d4a");
  var preTag = document.getElementById("style-text");
  var stand = document.getElementById("standby");

  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.backgroundColor = "#000" }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){ preTag.style.left = "500px" }, 7000);
  setTimeout(function(){ preTag.style.left = "100px" }, 8000);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.backgroundImage = "url('index.jpg')" }, 7000);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.fontSize = "5em" }, 7000);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.backgroundImage = "url('index1.jpg')" }, 7300);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.fontSize = "1em" }, 7400);
  setTimeout(function(){ stand.style.display = "block" }, 7600);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.backgroundImage = "url('No_signal.gif')" }, 7600);
  setTimeout(function(){ stand.style.display = "none" }, 8500);
  setTimeout(function(){ bod.style.backgroundImage = "none" }, 8500);

</script>
```

And also i know that i can write it using jQuery like in this way:

```
$(".a").fadeIn(3000,function(){
    $(".b").fadeIn(4000, function(){
        $(".c").fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
```

**But are there any better ways to doing these actions, cleaner?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like wow.js - http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html

Wow is predominately used for animations triggered by scroll but also has useful html data-attributes which can be added to each html element you wish to animate. E.G:

```
<section class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">
```

This gives an animation (Slide In Left), a duration (2 seconds) and a delay until the animation should fire (5 seconds).

For a CSS only solution, you could look into using keyframe animation. CSS has the `animation-delay` property which could fit your needs well - Here's a simple example:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay